# ParseError: expected "indent", got "!"

Tags: webpack, vue.js, stylus

I am trying to build an Vuejs application with stylus.
I install `stylus stylus-loader style-loader css-loader`  add added in build/webpack.base.conf.js at rules array.

```
{
  test: /\.styl$/,
  loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'stylus-loader']
}
```

and I created a empty file in src folder name `main.styl` and added in main.js.

when I run `npm run dev` its showing an error,

> Module build failed: ParseError: expected "indent", got "!"

What wrong goes here...

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you fix it?

Comment: I have the same problem :/

Answer (score 6):

Regarding the fact I had the same issue, and that you have a `build` directory with `webpack.base.conf.js` inside, I assume that you are using the [vuejs webpack boilerplate](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/) as I do.

The point is that this boilerplate already defines the loaders for Stylus files `.styl` or `.stylus`. It is indeed part of a plugin defined in either `build/webpack.dev.conf.js` or `build/webpack.prod.conf.js`, using function `styleLoaders` defined in `build/utils.js`. **You don't need to add any configuration** in `build/webpack.base.conf.js`.

However, if you need special options to be passed to `stylus-loader`, for instance if you need to [import a library](https://github.com/shama/stylus-loader#using-nib-with-stylus) or a [global stylus file](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/326) for all your components, you have to pass it in function `cssLoaders` in `build/utils.js`, *ie*:

```
const stylusOptions = {
  import: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'relative/path/to/file.styl')]
  // or other options
}

return {
  css: generateLoaders(),
  postcss: generateLoaders(),
  less: generateLoaders('less'),
  sass: generateLoaders('sass', { indentedSyntax: true }),
  scss: generateLoaders('sass'),
  stylus: generateLoaders('stylus', stylusOptions),
  styl: generateLoaders('stylus', stylusOptions)
}
```

Hope it helps, though this post is quite old.

Answer (score -1):

I met the same problem about import *.styl into the main.js.

My solution: open the webpack.base.conf.js, find the "module.rules" part, assert

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'stylus-loader'],
},
```

My project based on "vue^2.5.2", vue-cli^2.8.2, I hope that can help you.

my webpack.base.conf.js file:
[image]